# Variance of $X$, an uniformly random sum from a finite set $S$.

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, variance

This is from my class. Can I have an explanation of what going on in the last equality (i.e. $\operatorname{Var}\left(\varepsilon_{i}\right) s_{i}^{2}=\frac{1}{4} \sum_{i=1}^{k} s_{i}^{2}$)?

> - Let $S=\left\{s_{1}, s_{2}, \ldots, s_{k}\right\} \subseteq[n]$ be a largest set with distinct sums (i.e. the sums of elements in all $T \subset S$ are all different).
> - Let $X$ be a uniformly random sum from $S$.
> - $\Rightarrow X=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \varepsilon_{i} s_{i},$ where each    $\varepsilon_{i}$ is independent, uniform on {0,1}.
> - Let $\mu:=\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \mathbb{E}\left[\varepsilon_{i} s_{i}\right]=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{k} s_{i}$. (Actual value is unimportant)
> - Variables $\varepsilon_{i}$ are independent
> - $\Rightarrow \operatorname{Var}(X)=\operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} \varepsilon_{i} s_{i}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \operatorname{Var}\left(\varepsilon_{i}\right) s_{i}^{2}=\frac{1}{4} \sum_{i=1}^{k} s_{i}^{2} \leq \frac{1}{4} n^{2} k$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from the definition. Since $\varepsilon_i$ is a uniform r.v. on $\{0, 1\}$, we have
$$
\mathbb E[\varepsilon_i] = \sum_{x \in \{0, 1\}} x \mathbb P(\varepsilon_i = x) = 0\cdot \frac 1 2 + 1 \cdot \frac 1 2 = \frac 1 2,
$$
and we similarly obtain $\mathbb E[\varepsilon_i^2] = \frac 1 2$, so
$$
\mathrm{Var}(\varepsilon_i) = \mathbb E[\varepsilon_i^2] - \mathbb E[\varepsilon_i]^2 = \frac 1 2 - \frac 1 4 = \frac 1 4.
$$
This constant is then taken outside of the sum.

Comment: Thanks. I was expanding things out, but didn't realize $\mathbb E[\varepsilon_i] = \mathbb E[\varepsilon_i^2] = \frac 1 2$. Could you elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: Yes, I've edited the answer. Hope this helps.